# Cell blink in google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet which has 22 sheets. I want to blink a particular cell (suppose A1) in all 22 sheets when the file is opened. I don't know javascript. I managed a script from google but it only blinks only when A1 cell is edited in Sheet1 only, not on every sheet. I want to blink cell A1 in all 22 sheets when the file is opened not edited (because A1 is read-only cell. It will only blink as alert). The script is

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  
  if( activeCell == "A1" )
  {
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
      if( i%2 == 0 )
        mysheet.getRange("A1").setBackground("RED");
      else
        mysheet.getRange("A1").setBackground("WHITE");
      
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
  }
}
```

Please someone edit the script so that every sheet's A1 cell blink automatically when the file is opened. Thanks in advance.

I don't know javascript.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). What you are asking can be done, but it may not be as practical as you think. It could make more sense to show a small pop-up dialog box with something like `function onOpen(e) { e.source.toast('Attention'); }`.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you're asking for:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for (var j in allsheets) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) allsheets[j].getRange("A1").setBackground("RED");
      else allsheets[j].getRange("A1").setBackground("WHITE");
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(500);
  }
}
```

To make this script work:

1. Open a Google Sheets workbook
2. Click on the Extensions menu and pull down to Apps Script
3. Paste in the Apps Script shown above and make any adjustments (cell to blink; colors to blink)
4. Name the script (i.e. "Blink on All Sheets") Click the Save icon

For more info, see [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

Comment: The script may work, but it will take time to run. If you have 20 sheets, there will be 1,000 rounds of color changing and 50 rounds of sleeping, perhaps two minutes in total. In larger spreadsheets you may exceed the six-minute runtime limit. There will also be side effects like polluting version history and leaving cell `A1` red in all sheets. The `onOpen(e)` function is not a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) but a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). Was the answer partially generated with ChatGPT?